# Why covariance constraint subsumes the average power constraint?

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, optimization, information-theory

I am studying an optimization problem in the form of 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\underset{p(x)}{\text{maximize}}
& &  W\\
& \text{subject to}
& & 0 \preceq K_{X} \preceq S,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
in which  $K_{X}$ is the covariance matrix of  $X$,
and $S$ is a positive semidefinite matrix. The goal is to find optimal distribution (optimal $p(x)$) for that. The [paper](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~pramodv/pubs/LV06.pdf) says that since *the covariance constraint subsumes the average power constraint* we conclude that the same $p(x)$ is optimal for the following problem too:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\underset{p(x)}{\text{maximize}}
& &  W\\
& \text{subject to}
& & 0 \le  \operatorname{tr}(K_{X}) \le P.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Can anyone explain this?

My question is simply what asked in the title, but the following details might help. In that specific problem, $W \triangleq h(X +  Z_1) -  \mu h(X + Z_2)$ where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent Gaussian vectors and $\mu\ge 1$ is is an scalar, and the vector $X$ is independent of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, $h(\cdot)$ is the *differential entropy* function, and $P$ is a (scalar) constant.

Comment: Some more context and definitions might be helpful.  In particular, what is $W$?  How does $p(x)$ relate to $K_X$?  How does $S$ relate to $P$?  What is "the paper"?

Comment: I added those details.

Comment: You still have not said what $P$ is.

Comment: $P$ is constant (scalar).

Comment: @Bob Is it given in terms of $S$? It seems like the two problems could only be equivalent if $P$ is some function of the parameters of the original problem.

Comment: They are not equivalent. The paper says the first problem subsumes the second one, i.e., if a specific $p(x)$ is the answer for the first one, it will be the answer for the second one too.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the meaning of the word "subsumes". What they mean is that if you want to solve the second problem, you can do so by solving an instance of the first problem (in particular, by taking $S$ to be $P$ times the identity matrix).